# How to write a function to stratify sample by stratum size

Tags: r, function

I have 100 samples. I'd like to write a function to stratify them.

```
stratify <- function(s,size)
```

For example:
number of strata s=2, size = (20,80), stratum number = 1,2.

number of strata s=4, size=(25,25,25,25), stratum number = 1,2,3,4

...And more depending on what's passing to the function.

The desired result printed shoule be a matrix with Identifier number(1 TO 100) and the according stratum number.

For example for stratum s=2, straum size = (20,80), I know  I can do

```
ResultMatrix$Identifier <- 1:100
ResultMatrix$Stratum <- c(rep(1,20),rep(2,80))
```

But I don't know how to do this in a function when the stratum size is unkonwn.

Comment: It’s unclear to me what the function’s result is supposed to be: you say it’s supposed to be a matrix, but the code you show isn’t valid for matrices, the object `ResultMatrix` in your code needs to be list-like object (such as a `data.frame`).

Comment: The number of strata can be imputed by `length(size)` in a function.  So you don't need to pass that parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your desired output is a table, not a matrix, the following function works:

```r
stratify = function (sizes) {
    data.frame(
        Identifier = seq_len(sum(sizes)),
        Stratum = unlist(lapply(seq_along(sizes), function (i) rep(i, sizes[i])))
    )
}
```

Note that the argument `s` is unused (it’s always given by `length(sizes)`), so I’ve omitted it.